# Why is my javascript only validating a single check box?

Tags: javascript, validation

Here is my [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/DrewG85/yYPSS/)

I have no issue validating the first 3 text inputs, however when my validation gets to the check boxes and radio buttons, it only validates one check box and one radio button, rather than looping back through and re-checking each box/button.

So if I only enter the first radio button and the first check box, it allows submission. Also if I enter a checkbox and hit submit, there are no popups asking that I fill in the other check boxes, I have the same issue with the radio buttons, if I enter one of the radio buttons, it only alerts me to fill in check boxes and leaves out the other radio buttons.

What do I need to change in my loop counter? Any assistance is appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: when you post a question you are encouraged to post the minimal code to replicate your issue also. i know jsfiddle is a great site to test your script, but for future reference is better to keep the code and the question in the same place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in this two row

```
if (inputName.length > 0) if (element.name == inputName) returnValue++;
else returnValue++
```

now is executed like this

```
if (inputName.length > 0) {
    if (element.name == inputName) { 
        returnValue++;
    } else {
        returnValue++
    }
}
```

i think you need to wrap the ifs with brackets

```
if (inputName.length > 0) {
    if (element.name == inputName) { 
        returnValue++;
    }
} else {
    returnValue++  // i kept this but don't understand what it means...
}
```

EDIT:

i updated your fiddle and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yYPSS/2/) work as expected

Comment: Wow, thank you so very much!!! I'm still very new to js and as with any code, it seems very easy to get tripped up by even minor syntax errors, but I'm learning with help. thanks to people like you!!!